# Mapping gps coordinates with census tract Python

Tags: python, pandas, api, geolocation, census

I did not yet find an answer to solve my confusion of a small project I am working on.

My goal is to match a census block ID / block_fips to lat/lon pairs in my dataframe.

I have not worked with an API for complementing data in Python previously.

Here is a snippet of a dataset of lat and lon coordinates:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [40.760659, 40.768254, 40.761573], 'lon': [-73.980420, -73.988639, -73.972628]})
print(df)
```

I came across the Census conversion API https://www.fcc.gov/census-block-conversions-api. If using the Area API, how can I (1) obtain and then (2) match the "block_fips" to the first lat/lon pair, in this case "360610131001003" using Python in a Jupyter notebook in the Anaconda environment.

The output I wish is then:

```
dfcensus = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [40.760659, 40.768254, 40.761573], 'lon': [-73.980420, -73.988639, -73.972628], 'block': [360610131001003, 360610139003000, 360610112021004]})
print(dfcensus)
```

Many thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- a row by row call to the API is simplest approach
- API is simple to use, use **requests** building URL parameters documented in API
- just assign this back to new column in dataframe
- this has been run in a jupyter lab environment

```
import requests

url = "https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/block/find"

df = pd.DataFrame({"lat": [40.760659, 40.768254, 40.761573],
                   "lon": [-73.980420, -73.988639, -73.972628],})
df.assign(
    block=df.apply(
        lambda r: requests.get(
            url, params={"latitude": r["lat"], "longitude": r["lon"], "format": "json"}
        ).json()["Block"]["FIPS"],
        axis=1,
    )
)
```

|  | lat | lon | block |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40.7607 | -73.9804 | 360610131001003 |
| 1 | 40.7683 | -73.9886 | 360610139003000 |
| 2 | 40.7616 | -73.9726 | 360610112021004 |

Comment: do you know of a way to make the code more efficient, too? It works great on relatively small datasets, but once there are many entries (i.e. large geographical area) it consumes much time. Or maybe given it makes requests to a webpage there is no way to enhance speed (?).

Comment: optimisation will be through features of the data.  how many repeating long/lat pairs are there?  the most expensive part will be call to API.  reducing unneeded API calls will be simplest / most effective way to optimise

Comment: I just quickly coded up this API call.  is there a batch interface as well?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean, but it is a large csv file (800000 rows) that are analyzed/run by on the spot.

Comment: it's simple - an API call is expensive.  time to execute is effectively number of API calls.  reduce number of API calls and you reduce amount of time to execute.  So if there are multiple rows with same/similar lat/lon co-ordinates that give same bloc, call API once for combination to reduce number of API calls and reuse result across rows

Comment: Is there a way to pull the census tract boundaries and then determine whether the lat/long coordinates are in the boundary? That would be one call per tract, rather than one call per point of interest.